# Digital Low Pass Filter and PWM Signal

Tags: filters, analog-to-digital

I have a PWM signal going into an ADC.

After the ADC the signal is being filtered using an IIR single pole filter.

Performance is exactly what I want with one exception. The purpose of the filter is to average a voltage at the ADC that represents a current. For high duty cycles getting an estimation of the average current with the low pass filter is trivial. For low duty cycles the average can sometimes be zero or fluctuate too much, meaning the filter gives imprecise values at low duty cycles.

I would like to avoid this without too much complexity. Any ideas?

edit:

The frequency of the PWM being measured can be between 0 and 250Hz. I have DMA running the ADC values to a buffer, I'm not sure what the actual adc cycle rate is but the filter loop is 10kHz.

Increasing the sample rate is one thing. I will do that but the issue in my mind relates to the rate at which the signal decays. For 90% of the signal period the filter will be averaging using the value zero as an input, regardless of what the sample rate is. I'm more concerned about this.

[image]

Comment: it looks more like a challenge than a question. On dsp.SE site, the post would acquire more attention if it were focused on analysing and modifying signals (waveforms in this case) rather than talking about DMAs and ADCs. To make the scenario look as close as possible to a practical design problem, the proposed implementation might start with a time-to-digital converter, then the text could move on to explaining what you want to modify the TDC output to. This route would let experts concentrate on equations and algorithms, i.e., remain in their elements.

Comment: Also, maybe the TDC approach would work had your challenge happened to be the real design problem.

Comment: Would you care to tell us a bit more of what the figure shows? The aces are either not labelled or their labels are not visible. I feel there's a lack of information here. I'm not an expert by any means and maybe this is the reason I could use more information but maybe this is the case in general. So please take my comment with a grain of salt.

Comment: I would think that the cutoff of your lowpass filter is way too high. That should be determined by the bandwidth of the current signal and should be lower than the PWM rate

Comment: If you _know_ the signal is a PWM, that is rectangular wave with varying duty cycle (is it?), and you can process the signal digitally, why do you want to do some filtering, when you can write an algorithm to measure the duty cycle directly?